# Consequences of the principle of dependent choices (DC)

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

It is known that if we assume the axiom of determinacy every set of real numbers is lebesgue measurable. In order to study this, I'm following Jech's Set Theory book. There, Jech says that apart from the axiom of determinacy, it is necessary ZF+DC. However, I don't know why we need DC. Wouldn't the countable axiom of choice be enough?

Indeed, I don't know what are the consequences of DC and what we can't do without it.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Might be useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Baxiom-of-choice%5D+Dependent+Choice

Comment: Certainly DC is not necessary as we can always violate it high enough in the von Neumann hierarchy so that it doesn't effect measures on $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$. Hence, I'm not sure what exactly you're asking.